# IR Tracking Sensor (TCRT 5000 ) always gives led off as output

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-3, sensor, python-3

I am using a Raspberry PI3 Model B and TCRT 5000 sensor to monitor movement. I am using a Python script(Python3) to read the data from the sensor. 
Script used -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

TrackPin = 11
LedPin   = 12

def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)       # Numbers GPIOs by physical location
    GPIO.setup(LedPin, GPIO.OUT)   # Set LedPin's mode is output
    GPIO.setup(TrackPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.HIGH) # Set LedPin high(+3.3V) to off led

def loop():
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(TrackPin) == GPIO.LOW:
            print ("...led on")
            GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.LOW)  # led on
        else:
            print ("led off...")
            GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.HIGH) # led off

def destroy():
    GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.HIGH)     # led off
    GPIO.cleanup()                     # Release resource

if __name__ == '__main__':     # Program start from here
    setup()
    try:
         loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:  # When 'Ctrl+C' is pressed, the child program 
         destroy() will be  executed.
         destroy()
```

Circuit -

[image: Circuit Connected on bread board]

```
Red color shows 5v power supply used with 220 ohm resistor
Black color shows ground  used with 220 ohm resistor
Blue color shows output  used with 10k ohm resistor
```

Picture of sensor omitting light -
[image: As we can see from T there is light glowing.]

I tried to read data from GPIO 11 that is Pin 23. When do this the light on sensor indicating OUT always glows red.

I also changed the pin to Pin 11 which is GPIO 17. When do this the light on sensor indicating OUT won't glow.
Output i am getting in both cases are always -

```
led off...
led off... 
led off...
led off... 
led off...
led off...
led off...
led off...
led off...
led off...
..........
```

I went to many websites seeking solution but none worked for me. Am i doing something wrong ?